# random divs horizontally javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

New here. I am a sys-admin with medium experience with html/css/php. I've worked on modX, Wordpress and Joomla in the past, and now my boss wants something that requires javascript or jquery knowledge (less than basic in my case).

Problem description: .x-container is with fluid height and .x-column also, .ult-new has fixed height 230px with margin set in css (20px) and position relative. x-column has width: 22% and position relative and margin-right: 4%. And i need to display randomly each ult-new inside each x-column (inside each x-container). Those elements are created dynamically with php and shortcodes. So i need to vertically position them in random places in those columns and relative to each other (with 20px margin top and bottom).

As i understand i need to count the height of each x-column and than count the number of .ult-new elements in each of those columns. And than i need to posiotion those elements as absolute and do some math (first will be 0px from the top plus 20px margin, and then second element needs to be 230px from the top plus 20px margin top etc).

How do i translate this to javascript? Is there something else i don't see? :)

```html
<div class"x-container">

 <div class="x-column">

  <div class="ult-new">
    <!--some code here (text, hyperllinks etc)-->
  </div>
  
  <div class="ult-new">

  </div>
  
  <div class="ult-new">

  </div>

  <!--some code here (text, hyperllinks etc)-->

 </div>
 
 <div class="x-column">

  <div class="ult-new">

  </div>
  
  <div class="ult-new">

  </div>
  
  <div class="ult-new">

  </div>

 </div>

  <!--and many more x-column-->

</div>

<div class"x-container">

 <div class="x-column">

  <div class="ult-new">

  </div>
  
  <div class="ult-new">

  </div>
  
  <div class="ult-new">

  </div>

 </div>
 
 <div class="x-column">

  <div class="ult-new">

  </div>
  
  <div class="ult-new">

  </div>
  
  <div class="ult-new">

  </div>

 </div>

</div>

<!--and many more x-container-->
```

Comment: I am pretty sure your problem could be solved just using css by using flexbox. Flexbox allows you to automatically size as well as spread and fill remaining space. Take a look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for a good introduction.

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand what your doing but the best information i can give you is this jquery. now your gonna have to do some of the work to configure it but i believe in you!

```
var x;  // move horizontal
var y; // move vertical



 $('.YOURCLASS').css({"width":"50px","margin","50px","position":"absolute","transform":`translateX(${x})`,"transform":`translateY(${Y})`}) //sets styles
    $('.YOURCLASS').css("width") // gives the width of element
    var randomnum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); // random number 1-10
    y = randomnum
    x = randomnum
    // use position:absolute then pass x,y in
```